# SSL and .htaccess force https

Tags: ssl, https, mediatemple, csr

I have never done this before

This is my current `.htaccess` file, I want it to tell the browser to switch to HTTPS.

```
AddHandler php5-script .php

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?r=$1 [L,QSA]
```

The website [JacoInc.com](https://jacoinc.com/) has a SSL however Chrome gives this message:

```
The identity of this website has not been verified.
 • Server's certificate does not match the URL.
```

I don't know why this comes up. Is it because of MediaTemple or something that I'm doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a programming question (not for StackOverflow), and the clue is in the error message.

The certificate for the site you're linking to has the following Subject Alternative Names:

```
DNS Name: *.gridserver.com
DNS Name: gridserver.com
```

Therefore, it's only valid for these names (see [RFC 6125](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6125) and [RFC 2818](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2818#section-3.1)):

> If a subjectAltName extension of type dNSName is present, that MUST
> be used as the identity. Otherwise, the (most specific) Common Name
> field in the Subject field of the certificate MUST be used. Although
> the use of the Common Name is existing practice, it is deprecated and
> Certification Authorities are encouraged to use the dNSName instead.
>
> Matching is performed using the matching rules specified by
> [RFC2459].  If more than one identity of a given type is present in
> the certificate (e.g., more than one dNSName name, a match in any one
> of the set is considered acceptable.) Names may contain the wildcard
> character * which is considered to match any single domain name
> component or component fragment. E.g., *.a.com matches foo.a.com but
> not bar.foo.a.com. f*.com matches foo.com but not bar.com.

This has nothing to do with `.htaccess`.

As a side note, redirections via rewrite rules from `http://` to `https://` only happen after the `http://` request has been made. Make sure you stay on `https://` once you're on it, don't rely on this for all your links to be turned to `https://` automatically.